# Find words beginning with 's' using set/multiset

Tags: c++, count, set, find, multiset

The issue I'm having with this code stems from the last block of code for the get_words_beginning_s function.

```
    /*
Name:   xx
Date:   xx

Purpose:Read text from file, count number of words, unique words, word frequency, & number of words that begin with letter 's'
*/

#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <set>

using namespace std;

multiset<string> display_and_load_words(string filename);
set<string> get_unique_words(multiset<string>& words);
set<string> get_words_beginning_s(multiset<string>& words);

int main() {
    cout << "The Word Counter program\n\n";

    string filename = "dickens.txt";

    cout << "FILE TEXT: ";
    //display_text(filename);

    auto words = display_and_load_words(filename);
    cout << "WORD COUNT: " << words.size() << endl << endl;

    auto unique_words = get_unique_words(words);
    auto words_beginning_s = get_words_beginning_s(words);

    cout << unique_words.size() << " UNIQUE WORDS: ";
    for (string word : unique_words) {
        cout << word << ' ';
    }
    cout << endl << endl;

    cout << "COUNT PER WORD: ";
    for (string word : unique_words) {
        cout << word << '=' << words.count(word) << ' ';
    }
    cout << endl << endl;

    cout << "WORDS THAT BEGIN WITH 'S': ";
    for (string word : words_beginning_s) {
        cout << word << ' ';
    }
    cout << endl << endl;
}

multiset<string> display_and_load_words(string filename) {
    multiset<string> words;
    ifstream infile(filename);

    if (infile) {
        string word;
        while (infile >> word) {
            cout << word << ' ';

            string new_word = "";
            for (char c : word) {
                if (c == '.' || c == ',') {
                    continue;               // remove punctuation
                }
                else if (isupper(c)) {
                    new_word += tolower(c); // convert to lowercase
                }
                else {
                    new_word += c;
                }
            }
            words.insert(new_word);      // add word 
        }
        cout << endl << endl;
        infile.close();
    }
    return words;
}

set<string> get_unique_words(multiset<string>& words) {
    set<string> unique_words;

    for (string word : words) {
        auto search = unique_words.find(word);
        if (search == unique_words.end()) {
            unique_words.insert(word);
        }
    }
    return unique_words;
}


set<string> get_words_beginning_s(multiset<string>& words) {
    set<string> words_beginning_s;

    for (string word : words) {
        auto search = words_beginning_s.find(word);
        if (search == words_beginning_s.end()) {
            for (int i = 0; i < words_beginning_s.size(); ++i) {
                if (words_beginning_s[0] == 's') {
                words_beginning_s.insert(word);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return words_beginning_s;
}
```

If working with set/multiset, how does one compare positional values within each separate word itself, rather the entire words? Example string in text file - "John goes to the store": Whereas normally a simple for loop can be used with the initial position to compare values and count number of times it appears (something like)-

```
for (int i = 0; i < words_beginning_s.length(); ++i) {
            if (words_beginning_s[0] == 's') {
            ++s_word;
            }
```

This does not work when using set/multiset. Pretty new to this, so sorry if this question seems dumb.

Comment: Does it have to be a `set` of some kind?

Comment: It does have to be a set.

Comment: I know. That's where I'm getting the error. What I am not quite getting is what way it needs to search the beginning of each word when using a set.

Comment: Unrelated: `else if (isupper(c)) { new_word += tolower(c); } else { new_word += c; }` would be better with just `else new_word += tolower(c);` - There's no need to check if it's uppercase first.

Comment: Look for words between [`lower_bound("s")`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set/lower_bound) and `lower_bound("t")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `multiset`s member function [`lower_bound`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/multiset/lower_bound) to get iterators to a range and then create a `set` from that range.

Example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <set>
#include <string>

std::set<std::string> get_words_beginning_s(const std::multiset<std::string>& words) {
    // create a set from the iterators you get from lower_bound("s") and lower_bound("t"):
    return {words.lower_bound("s"), words.lower_bound("t")};
}

int main() {
    std::multiset<std::string> words{
        "foo", "slayer", "bar", "sepultura", "tesseract", "skinny puppy", "yello"
    };

    for(const std::string& word : get_words_beginning_s(words)) {
        std::cout << word << '\n';
    }
}
```

Output:

```
sepultura
skinny puppy
slayer
```

Comment: Thank you for your solution @Ted. For some reason my code stopped working when I tried this, but when I removed the ```const``` out of the function, it worked. It stops working working again if I try to remove ```const``` out of the for loop.  Is this because at that point the program will modify the value otherwise, whereas in the function you may want something to change?

Comment: @DukeJohnson  Great! You aren't allowed to modify values in a `set` that is included in the comparator used for the type (`std::string` in this case). If you must modify a value, you must extract it from the `set`, modify it and then insert it again.

Comment: I see. Thanks a lot for the help and explanations.